# Does the proof of law of total expectation: $E(X) = E(E(X|Y))$ require change of integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, expected-value

The law of total expectation (or Tower rule) states that for random variables $X, Y$
$$E(X) = E(E(X|Y))$$

The proof is

\begin{align*}
E(E(X|Y)) &= \int_y \int_x xf(x|y) dx f(y)dy\\
&= \int_y \int_x xf(x, y) dx dy\\
&\overset{*}{=} \int_x x f(x) dx\\
&= E(X)
\end{align*}

For the step with *, does it hold only if $$\int_y \int_x xf(x, y)dx dy = \int_x \int_y xf(x, y)dy dx?$$

That is, does the step with * require change of integrals, i.e., Fubini's theorem? Or can the above proof hold without any additional assumptions?

Comment: The law is applicable any two r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ with $E|X| <\infty$. You cannot assume existence of densities etc, so your proof is  unacceptable.

Comment: That is a simple but not very general/formal proof. Wikipedia has a general proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case

Comment: @LouisPan It's from a set of lecture notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the proofs I have seen require Fubini's theorem to exchange the integrals, see for instance [here.](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/11/14/proof-total-expectation/)